# Чистый html и css или extjs?

Tags: html, extjs, css

Помогите определиться. Что лучше будет. Сделать интерфейс чисто на html и css или extjs

Comment: @Doj, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Doj Вам для реализации админки или чего-то другого? Помнится, что админка [CMS MODx](http://modx.com/) написана на нём. 

В последний раз работал с этим фреймворком года 3-4 назад. Довольно тяжелое решение, как в освоении, так и по производительности. Кроме того, как только начнёте использовать его, у Вас появятся масса вопросов, которые, скорее всего, Вы будите задавать здесь. Боюсь, что ответов будет не так много.

Если всё-таки админка, то посмотрите [ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin), данное решение написано на AngularJS.

Answer (score 3):

Extjs не просто путь создания верстки, в отличие от "чистого html+css". Данный фреймворк значительно расширяет возможности управления компонентами и отслеживания состояний. Кроме того, существует множество вещей, которые невозможны без JS в принципе, соответственно, невозможны на чистом HTML+CSS.

Как всегда, решение зависит от конкретной задачи. Но раз возник вопрос именно в данной формулировке, то используйте html+css. Дешевле и быстрее выйдет. ExtJS - продвинутое решение совершенно другого уровня.